# How to create alpahnumeric identifiers that count upwards?

Tags: java

I'd like to create some sort of ID that should have the following format:

```
A1
A2
..
A9
B1
B2
..
B9
C1
..
```

Thus, the numbers count should go from 1-9, and the letter should increase everytime the number 9 is exceeded.

Are there libraries that already provide this sort of functionality? If not, how is this "pattern" called in general?

Comment: What will happen if more than 26*9 ID's are needed?

Comment: This will (probably) never happen in my case, but anyhow I would not mind if the IDs would then get an aditional letter like AA1, AB1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
class IDGenerator{
    char c ='A';
    int next = 1;
    public String getNextID(){
        String id = Character.toString(c) + Integer.toString(next++);
        if(next>9){
           next =1;
           c++;
        }
        return id;
    }

}
```

Note that this will work up to Z9

Answer (score 1):

You won't find this in a standard library, but you can roll your own loop for this:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        String id = Character.toString(c) + i;
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

As for the "pattern", I'd say this is the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) `{A,...,Z} x {1,...,9}` and cartesian products are usually implemented as a series of nested loops (two in this case) which iterate over the elements; you can modify the end points of the iteration variables to obtain the range of values you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as "inspiration" or guide to create your own method:

```
    int count = 1;
    char x = 'A';

    while(count != 11) {
        if(count == 10) {
            x = (char)(x + 1);
            count = 1;
        }
        System.out.println(count + "" + x);
        count++;
    }
```

This will print what you want and then some... :)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    for (char i =  'A'; i <= 'Z' ; i++) {
           for(int j=1;j<10;j++){
              String id=""+i+j;
              System.out.println(id);
          }
    }
```